# How can I create a file uploader using JSP and servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

Recently I thought of creating a file uploader using JSP/Servlet. In the JSP page there will be a link. On clicking the link corresponding action class is called. So when the upload starts I must get the info status on my JSP page. But if the link is clicked again I must show that some message like one import is already running.

Is something like this already available? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

One of the Jquery File Upload

http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/

You may find many more examples if you google it

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a bunch of file upload javascript libraries. Google it and see for yourself. JQuery is super simple to work with and works with Servlet libraries like Struts. Hope this helps!