# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, weblogic

I am handling file uploads by a multipart filter as described [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html). I created a WAR file and deployed on Weblogic 10.3.3 server and got error:

```
<Dec 8, 2011 5:37:07 PM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[ServletContext@26087289[app:playground module:playground.war path:/playground spec-version:null]] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at net.balusc.webapp.MultipartFilter.parseRequest(MultipartFilter.java:169)
    at net.balusc.webapp.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:123)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3684)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Then I deployed same WAR file on Tomcat 7.0.11 server and it is successfully running. How is this caused and how can I deploy successfully on Weblogic?

Comment: You may refer this for Ajax file upload http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344766/how-can-i-create-a-file-uploader-using-jsp-and-servlet/8352014#8352014

Comment: @BalusC  kindly check original question i have edited it.

Comment: In the future, you should have asked a **new** question for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Deployment on Weblogic 10.3.3 results in an error:
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;)Ljava/util/List;
>
> Deployment on Tomcat 7.0.11 is successful.

Weblogic already ships with Apache Commons FileUpload libraries. This error indicates that they are of an older version than which you have in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

You have at least 3 options:

1. Remove the JARs from `/WEB-INF/lib`.
2. Replace them by exactly the same version as Weblogic is using.
3. Change the Weblogic classloading policy to load classes from application first.

Comment: what is the correct maven dependency for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following API to upload files to JBoss Server
http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/index.html

Comment: can u direct me any code available on net for uploading large files(file size :1 GB)

Comment: @user752590 You can configure maximum file size; you'll likely need to configure both commons fileupload and jboss.

Answer (score 0):

Check If your Jar Library has duplicate Jar files with Different versions.
Delete the old version file.