# org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(Ljakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Z

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, apache-commons-fileupload

I migrated JSF javax to jakarta. However, I am getting an error like the title. I couldn't find the reason for this. Thank you for your help on this.

Web Server GlassFish 6.2.5
Jakarta : jakarta.jakartaee-api 9.1.0
PrimeFaces 11.0.0
OmniFaces : 4.0-M17

I reviewed the example here but it was not possible to adapt it for GlassFish

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353704/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-commons-fileupload-servlet-servletfileup)

Log

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(Ljakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Z
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(GzipResponseFilter.java:183)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at com.kurtomerfaruk.core.filters.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLessToExtension(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:185)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:142)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:128)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:84)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:34)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
]]
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>





            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                <version>11.0.0</version>
                <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.extensions/primefaces-extensions -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
                <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
                <version>11.0.6</version>
                <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
                <artifactId>resources-monacoeditor</artifactId>
                <version>11.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.omnifaces/omnifaces -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
                <version>4.0-M17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-envers -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.24</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
                <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-RC2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>6.20.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(Ljakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Z

Technically speaking, this error is correct and fully expected.

The dependency which you have there,

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

has only the following method available,

> org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(L**javax**/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Z

and not the one which your application is trying to look for.

But you do actually **not** need Commons FileUpload at all. It's a leftover from age-old practices. Using this library is not necessary anymore since introduction of Servlet API version 3.0 in 2009 (more than a decade ago already!). Starting with GlassFish version 3.x, parsing uploaded files is already natively supported by the server itself, without the need for any 3rd party library such as Commons FileUpload. See also [How can I upload files to a server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-can-i-upload-files-to-a-server-using-jsp-servlet) for an explanation/interpretation in plain vanilla JSP/Servlet terms.

According to this related question, [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null / throws an error / not usable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded), you should since PrimeFaces version 5.x already be able to use server-native file upload parsing functionality instead of using the 3rd party Apache Commons FileUpload library.

Perform the following changes to your application:

1. In the `pom.xml`, **remove** the `commons-fileupload` dependency.
2. In the `web.xml`, **remove** the `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` entries associated with the `org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter`.
3. In the `web.xml`, **remove** any `<context-param>` associated with `primefaces.UPLOADER`.

That's it. The PrimeFaces file upload component in your application will now automatically use the server-native file upload parsing functionality.